# How to speed up this Python function?

Tags: python, pandas

I hope it is OK to ask questions of this type.

I have a `get_lags` function that takes a data frame, and for each column, shifts the column by each n in the list `n_lags`. So, if `n_lags = [1, 2]`, the function shifts each column once by 1 and once by 2 positions, creating new lagged columns in this way.

```
def get_lags (df, n_lags):
    data =df.copy()
    data_with_lags = pd.DataFrame()
    for column in data.columns:
        for i in range(n_lags[0], n_lags[-1]+1):
            new_column_name = str(column) + '_Lag' + str(i)
            data_with_lags[new_column_name] = data[column].shift(-i) 
    data_with_lags.fillna(method = 'ffill', limit = max(n_lags), inplace = True)
    return data_with_lags
```

So, if:

```
df.columns
ColumnA
ColumnB
```

Then, `get_lags(df, [1 , 2]).columns` will be:

```
ColumnA_Lag1
ColumnA_Lag2
ColumnB_Lag1
ColumnB_Lag2
```

**Issue:** working with data frames that have about 100,000 rows and 20,000 columns, this takes forever to run. On a 16-GB RAM, core i7 windows machine, once I waited for 15 minutes to the code to run before I stopped it. Is there anyway I can tweak this function to make it faster?

Comment: Maybe use `df.shift`

Comment: Well at a minimum it appears your nested `for` is `O(n^2)`, so how can you optimize it?

Comment: You are replicating your data N times. Consider a different approach? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `shift` + `concat`. Here's the concise version -

```
def get_lags(df, n_lags):
    return pd.concat(
       [df] + [df.shift(i).add_suffix('_Lag{}'.format(i)) for i in n_lags],
       axis=1
    )
```

And here's a more memory-friendly version, using a for loop -

```
def get_lags(df, n_lags):
    df_list = [df]
    for i in n_lags:
        v = df.shift(i)
        v.columns = v.columns + '_Lag{}'.format(i)    
        df_list.append(v)

    return pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to your case (I hope I understand what you're trying to do correctly), but you can speed it up massively by not doing it in the first place. Can you treat your columns like a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)?

Instead of changing the columns afterwards, keep track of:

- how many columns can you use (how many lag items for each entry)
- what was the last lag column used
- (optionally) how many times you "rotated"

So instead of moving the data, you do something like:

```
current_column = (current_column + 1) % total_columns
```

and write to that column next.

Comment: I am not familiar with this concept. Thanks for your answer anyways.